# Examples and exercises of code improvement

Tags: haskell, optimization, functional-programming

[This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_QuickCheck2) intro to QuickCheck2 starts off with a beautiful example of code improvement.

**Before**

```
getList = find 5 where
     find 0 = return []
     find n = do
       ch <- getChar
       if ch `elem` ['a'..'e'] then do
             tl <- find (n-1)
             return (ch : tl) else
           find n
```

**After**

```
-- A thin monadic skin layer
getList :: IO [Char]
getList = fmap take5 getContents

-- The actual worker
take5 :: [Char] -> [Char]
take5 = take 5 . filter (`elem` ['a'..'e'])
```

**Where can we find more examples of optimizations like this?**

Where we have some code that works, but smells for some reason (hard to test, not reusable, etc.), and then we find a smart way to make it good enough.

What I'm after is not theory, best practises or tools of analysis, but actual **examples** or, even better, **exercises**.

Comment: You might not want theory, but the theory at work here is that you should always separate things that do IO from things that do computation. I think this is a quite simple principle, so unless you want to rephrase in broader terms, there isn't much more to say.

Comment: An exercise could be: "How would you improve this code? Would you improve it at all?" with the first version of `getList` given, and our task is to find a solution. I'm asking for a source where we may find a bunch of such exercises. And mixing side effecting code with pure computation is not the only possible weakness to improve.

Answer (score 2):

Try hlint, it gives you suggestions on how to improve your code: http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/hlint/

Since you are asking for specific examples, here's one from Real World Haskell on how to get ride of 'staircasing': http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html#x_JR

And then, of course, the more you write actual code, the more you'll see how you can make it more concise.